# how to debug checkout via $class: 'GitSCM'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have following code:

```
skipDefaultCheckout()
   (...)
        checkout([
          $class: 'GitSCM',
          branches: scm.branches,
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
          extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false]],
          submoduleCfg: [],
          userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
        ])
```

How do I debug the execution of this? I am hitting

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

error, but I don't know why. Any hints Guys? Is it possible to print out values of variables of this class? For example: scm.branches?

Comment: please show (obfuscated) input for ```userRemoteConfigs```. Variables are stored as ENV starting with ```GIT_```. Due to a problem in repos, check for ```GIT_URL``` and ```GIT_BRANCH```.

Comment: I need to add that I am trying to implement custom checkout and I have `skipDefaultCheckout()` enabled in order to do so.

Comment: If I try to print out env with `skipDefaultCheckout()` the job fails before print with the error *not a git repository*. If I comment it out, I can print variables: `GIT_URL_1=http://domain:7990/scm/projectname/project.git` and `GIT_BRANCH=PR-XXXX`

Comment: Is it even possible to `skipDefaultCheckout()` and use `$class: 'GitSCM',` in the code with the variables automatically passed to the job? If I have the skip disabled I have checkout being done twice, defaut one, and then another.

Comment: Good question, I think they're not. Tried it hardcoded? Generate here: ```JENKINS-URL/pipeline-syntax/``` If it is working with the same values it is not, I guess :)

Comment: This does not work either. I am going to create a retry wrapper for git command on slave node instead, I give up on this plugin.